# How can I change the template of a form in sfDoctrineGuardPlugin?

Tags: forms, authentication, symfony1

How can I change the template of a form in sfDoctrineGuardPlugin?

That is, I need to change the HTML (class, id) of the input elements (username, password) of a login form provided by sfDoctrineGuardPlugin.

I've changed `apps/app_name/modules/sfGuardAuth/templates/singinSuccess.php`, but it then just echoes `$form` (I need to change contents of that part - `$form`):

```
  <form action="<?php echo url_for('@sf_guard_signin') ?>" method="post">
    <table>
       <?php echo $form ?>
    </table>
    <input type="submit" class="go_button" value="ir" />
    <a href="<?php echo url_for('@sf_guard_password') ?>"><?php echo __('Forgot your password?') ?></a>
  </form>
```

(It really should be something like changing a _form.php => I can't find this, though :S)

Thank you all for any answers provided =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the sign in form class (forget it's name), there will be something like:

```
'username' => new sfWidgetFormInput(array(), array())
```

Modify that to:

```
'username' => new sfWidgetFormInput(array(), array('id' => 'jibbly', 'class' => 'wibbly'))
```

Comment: Great! Thanks, Coronatus. That was helpful. Any trick on how to modify completly the html produced by the plugin?

In the extra docs all they say is this:
<quote>
If you want to change the actual HTML emitted, you can obtain the formatter and override whatever settings are desired

    $this->getWidgetSchema()->getFormFormatter()->setRowFormat(
      "<tr>\n  <th align=\"right\">%label%</th>\n  <td>%error%%field%%help%%hidden_fields%</td>\n</tr>\n"
</quote>

But I would like to completly write a _form.php template to render it. Don't know how to do it, though :S

Thx